# Unable to share /mnt/share-name/www folder in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, samba

I am new to Ubuntu I am trying to create a small local web server. But it seems like there is so much permission problem in Ubuntu.

I have a VOLUME with a www folder in it. I change the path of my www folder in my apache. But when I access that folder it says me that `"Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."`

And I want to share the same www folder in my all the local network, so all the users can access it.

But I can not do that. Please suggest if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to share this folder via a web server (eg. Apache / Nginx) or do you want your colleagues to be able to access the contents of the folder in a way that's something like FTP / SFTP?

Comment: Yes. you got me right. But its not working. We are not able to create any folder or copy any file in the system.

Comment: Okay sorry for this question but can you please tell exactly if you want FTP or Webserver access? (Really sorry but I wan't to get you right)

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea of this purpose but this is the common permission method

```
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/share-name/www
```

Edited just for you

**NOTE: THIS ALLOWS READ, WRITE AND EDIT**

Comment: No not this is allowing me to do that.

Comment: Try it but without the sudo

Comment: Operation not permitted error.

Comment: Okay try this: sudo chmod -R 775 /mnt/share-name/www

Comment: How do you execute this command? Via Terminal or in a virtual terminal from a hosting company? Do you have access on this directory? Is you user in the sudo group?

Comment: via terminal. This is installed on my own computer. Actually it was working fine when i first create all new partition then i again reformat the main boot drive. After that i am facing this issue.